# Evaluation of an improper integral with complex exponential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

Are there any convenient ways to calculate an integral of the form
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{a_1 e^{j\omega\alpha}+a_2e^{j\omega\beta}}{1 + a_1a_2e^{j\omega\gamma}}d\omega$$
where $a_1,a_2,\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are real constants and $j=\sqrt{-1}$? The solution probably contains Dirac delta functions since the integral can be viewed as an inverse Fourier transform of a periodic function. Constants do not matter much, we can use specific numbers, say $a_1=2, a_2=3, \alpha=3, \beta=4$ and $\gamma=5$; the good method is what is of general interest..

Comment: Can you write the numerator as a linear combination of the denominator and the derivative of the denominator? Just a random thought. (Another thought, is this integral always convergent?)

Comment: I guess when doing what @imranfat suggests, you get a constant factor in the integrand, hence the integral will diverge in this case.

Comment: You are right, there was actually a typo in the question that I corrected it. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: This is definite integral, edit the title and tags